# How do I drop NAs where all cells have an NA in the columns I specify?

Tags: r, na

I am trying to drop rows with `NA`s. The NAs need to be in all the columns I specify. For example, if I specify `Tickets`, `Group` then there needs to be `NA`s in both columns for each row to dictate the row be dropped. I tried doing
`df %>% drop_na(Tickets, Group)` but got an error saying `unexpected ,` and `)`.  Basically, there are no NAs in `City`, `State`, or `Date`, and I want to remove all the rows with `NA`s in ALL the other columns.

| City | State | Date | Tickets | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-01-01 | NA | NA |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-02-01 | NA | NA |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-03-01 | 4 | NA |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 1 |

This is what I want:

| City | State | Date | Tickets | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-03-01 | 4 | NA |
| Chicago | IL | 2021-03-01 | 3 | 1 |

TLDR: I am trying to drop rows which have an `NA` value in all specified columns.

I'd appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
subset(df1, rowSums(is.na(df1[c("Tickets", "Group")])) < 2)
     City State       Date Tickets Group
3 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       4    NA
4 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       3     1
```

---

Or with `if_any` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(if_any(c(Tickets, Group), complete.cases))
     City State       Date Tickets Group
1 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       4    NA
2 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       3     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(City = c("Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago"
), State = c("IL", "IL", "IL", "IL"), Date = c("2021-01-01", 
"2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-01"), Tickets = c(NA, NA, 
4L, 3L), Group = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!is.na(Tickets) | !is.na(Group))
#     City State       Date Tickets Group
#1 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       4    NA
#2 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use negated `if_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!if_all(c(Tickets, Group), is.na))
```

```
   City State       Date Tickets Group
1 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       4    NA
2 Chicago    IL 2021-03-01       3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, everyone. Helpful to problem solve this. I think I found a solution. To anyone wondering:

I found the rows with all NAs by slightly editing a poster above's code. I then anti-joined it with my df that has all observations to get my desired outcome.

```
data_NA <-
df %>% 
filter(is.na(Tickets) & is.na(Group))

df <-
df %>%
anti_join(data_NA)
```

Comment: There is no need for the creation of an intermediate object followed by the anti_join. We can just use a negation operator (`!`) and an OR operator (`|`) to filter your selected rows OUT instead of IN: `filter(!(is.na(Tickets) | is.na(Group)))`